# "A" Vs "The" Vs "It" Vs "One" Vs "Any"

Tags: grammar, articles, determiners

In the following example, should I use **a, any, the, it,** or **one**?

- Yesterday my friend told me someone had parked a truck in our playground but when I reached there I did not see **a truck/it/any trucks/the truck/one.**

Answer (score 0):

All of them are acceptable, however, my personal preference would be for one of the following three it/any trucks/one